# How to assign a material to a smoke domain

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am trying to assign a material to the smoke simulation I have created.
For creating the simulation I added a cube, and I click object->quick effect->quick Smoke.
Then I have setted the smoke parameters and started the simulation.
I can't assign any material to the smoke domain, or to the smoke itself, it remains purple in color.
Also adding a principled volume in "Shader Editor" has no effect at all on the purple color of the volume.
I attach 2 images to show what I am trying to explain.[image: 2 Screenshots which expains the material assign problem]

Comment: IIRC Smoke generates particles, so a principled shader hooked to the the surface input works better than a a principled volume hooked to the volume input. Have you tried that?

Comment: Quicksmoke operator doesn't produce any particles. The smoke simulator uses a voxel-based volume, which is accessed via the volume socket of the material output node.

Answer (score 0):

Your shader assignment looks correct to me.

I suspect the purple color does not come from the smoke shader itself, but rather from a missing texture somewhere else like the world shader for example. Could you check that ?

Otherwise, a simple test could be to open a new fresh scene, do a quicksmoke on the default cube, setup the domain shader ans see how it goes.
If it still fails, then maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks, the world environmental shader was the issue. I unplugged it from the environmental output, re-opened the hdr image, plug it again, and the issue was resolved.